# Slow performance in PyCharm Python console when working with large pandas Data Frames

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pycharm

I'm experiencing significant slowdowns in the PyCharm Python console when working with large pandas DataFrames. The console becomes unresponsive for 10-15 seconds when attempting to display information about a DataFrame, particularly when typing the DataFrame variable name (e.g., 'df'). I'm using PyCharm Community Edition 3.4.1, Python 2.7.3, and pandas 0.14 on macOS 10.9.4 with 8 GB of RAM.

The size of my DataFrame is considerable:

> In[94]: df.values.nbytes + df.index.nbytes + df.columns.nbytes
> Out[94]: 2229198184

I've tried the following to mitigate the issue:

1. Using `df.head()` or `df.tail()` to display a subset of the DataFrame.
2. Exploring the DataFrame in steps (e.g., checking column names, data types, and basic information).
3. Adjusting the maximum heap size in PyCharm console settings.

However, the problem persists. Are there any additional optimizations or settings I can apply to improve the performance of the PyCharm Python console when dealing with large pandas DataFrames? Could it be related to the versions of PyCharm, Python, or pandas I'm using?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!